# Qt Designer How to Make Frame Fit Screen

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to create a GUI as pictured below. So far, I am using 3 frames (topbar, sidebar, and body) as the basics for splitting the GUI up. In the future, I plan to have navigation buttons on the sidebar, and body to give you a better idea of what I am trying to do.

However, I am struggling to figure out how to make the actual frames fill out the whole window when it resized. While I am new to Qt designer, I am aware of the layout feature and I have attempted to utilize it. For example the blue frame with the vertical layout, but this seems to only work on other widgets and not frames. Going back to my example, if I add the vertical layout to the blue part, it will stretch the line edit to fill the entire blue region (I want the line edit to be the size it is now) but it won't cause the blue region to fill the rest of the frame.

Is there a better widget to use for separating the GUI and adding background colors other than the frame container that I am using? Most of the examples I have seen, keep the layouts very basic, and I have not seen one where someone tries to break it up like this.

My work so far

[image]

Wire frame that shows what I am trying to do

[image]

Comment: To set a "main" layout for the top level window right click on an empty area and select the preferred layout from the relative submenu.

Comment: I can see this option, however, that causes the whole GUI to follow a single layout when I would like three different layouts for the three different regions. Is there a way to have different layouts for each frame?

Comment: Layouts can be nested, you can drag a new layout from the widget box into an existing one. In your case, use a grid as a main layout, then add a vertical layout for the left "sidebar", an horizontal for the top bar, and a new grid layout for the central part.